# Issues in displaying year by year line plot using bokeh (pyspark dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, bokeh, line-plot

I have an issue when I try to displaying line plot from pyspark dataframe using bokeh, it was displayed successfully but it shows what I'm not expected. The problem is some line plot dots are not connected year by year sequentially.

Previously I tried to sort the source data frame using orderBy :

```
# Join df_max, and df_avg to df_quake_freq    
df_quake_freq = df_quake_freq.join(df_avg, ['Year']).join(df_max, ['Year'])    
df_quake_freq = df_quake_freq.orderBy(asc('Year'))    
df_quake_freq.show(5)
```

And the output is :
[dataframe source for line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E2km.jpg)

This is code for plotting:

```
    # Create a magnitude plot
def plotMagnitude():
    # Load the datasource
    cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        yrs = df_quake_freq['Year'].values.tolist(),
        avg_mag = df_quake_freq['Avg_Magnitude'].round(1).values.tolist(),
        max_mag = df_quake_freq['Max_Magnitude'].values.tolist()
    ))
    
    # Tooltip
    TOOLTIPS = [
        ('Year', ' @yrs'),
        ('Average Magnitude', ' @avg_mag'),
        ('Maximum Magnitude', ' @max_mag')
    ]
    
    # Create the figure
    mp = figure(title='Maximum and Average Magnitude by Year',
               plot_width=1150, plot_height=400,
               x_axis_label='Years',
               y_axis_label='Magnitude',
               x_minor_ticks=2,
               y_range=(5, df_quake_freq['Max_Magnitude'].max() + 1),
               toolbar_location=None,
               tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
    
    # Max Magnitude
    mp.line(x='yrs', y='max_mag', color='#cc0000', line_width=2, legend='Max Magnitude', source=cds)
    mp.circle(x='yrs', y='max_mag', color='#cc0000', size=8, fill_color='#cc0000', source=cds)
    
    # Average Magnitude 
    mp.line(x='yrs', y='avg_mag', color='yellow', line_width=2, legend='Avg Magnitude', source=cds)
    mp.circle(x='yrs', y='avg_mag', color='yellow', size=8, fill_color='yellow', source=cds)
    
    mp = style(mp)
    
    show(mp)
    
    return mp

plotMagnitude()
```

The output is :
[line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em2Xj.jpg)

We can see from the picture that some dots are not connected sequentially, for example like 1965-1967-1966

Comment: Bokeh just plots the points in the order they are provided. They are evidently not coming in sorted according to year, so you will need to sort all the columns together according to the year.

Comment: I already sort all columns in the data frame according to the year using orderBy(), but still no effect

Comment: I suggest printing the value of `df_quake_freq['Year'].values.tolist()` inside `plotMagnitude` to verify that it is not, in fact, sorted at the point you are passing it to Bokeh. Your `plotMagnitude` seems to be relying on global variables outside the function. You could make things simpler to reason about by having it accept the dataframe to plot as a parameter, so there is no confusion about what value will be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! now my problem is solved, you are right, the 'plotMagnitude' function is relying on global variables, so to handle this I put 'sort.values()' inside the function to make the line-plot dots connected sequentially. @bigreddot

Comment: Just make sure you are sorting all the columns in the same way as you sort the years. Also please help keep the `[bokeh]` tag tidy and self-answer / accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, the reason why the dots are not sequenced is that `plotMagnitude` function is relying on global variables, so to handle this I put
`sort.values()` inside the function. This is the syntax:

```
def plotMagnitude():
# Load the datasource
cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    yrs = df_quake_freq['Year'].sort_values().values.tolist(),
    avg_mag = df_quake_freq['Avg_Magnitude'].round(1).values.tolist(),
    max_mag = df_quake_freq['Max_Magnitude'].values.tolist()
```